# Can't use UsedRange with MergedAreas - Office-JS

Tags: excel, office-js

I have a function that I've used and shared on this site previously that now seems to not work. I'm wondering if a change in the JS/API has broken something or whats causing the issue.

Note: Not sure if it matters, but I'm 100% on Desktop Excel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-getmergedareasornullobject-member(1)

This works:

```
console.log('START DEFINED RNG')
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var rng = ws.getRange("A1:A2")
//var rng = ws.getUsedRange(true)
var mergedAreas = rng.getMergedAreasOrNullObject();
mergedAreas.load(["areas"]);
await context.sync()
console.log('SYCNED')
```

This used to work!:

```
console.log('START USED_RNG')
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
//var rng = ws.getRange("A1:A2")
var rng = ws.getUsedRange(true)
var mergedAreas = rng.getMergedAreasOrNullObject();
mergedAreas.load(["areas"]);
await context.sync()
console.log('SYCNED')
```

This is error:

```
InvalidOperation: This operation is not permitted for the current object.
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      code: "InvalidOperation",
      data: undefined,
      debugInfo: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         code: "InvalidOperation",
         errorLocation: "Range.getMergedAreasOrNullObject",
         fullStatements: [ ],
         message: "This operation is not permitted for the current object.",
         statement: "var mergedAreasOrNullObject = usedRange.getMergedAreasOrNullObject();",
         surroundingStatements: [
            0: "var workbook = context.workbook;",
            1: "var worksheets = workbook.worksheets;",
            2: "var activeWorksheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();",
            3: "var usedRange = activeWorksheet.getUsedRange(...);",
            4: "// Instantiate {usedRange}",
            5: "// >>>>>",
            6: "var mergedAreasOrNullObject = usedRange.getMergedAreasOrNullObject();",
            7: "// <<<<<",
            8: "// Instantiate {mergedAreasOrNullObject}",
            9: "mergedAreasOrNullObject.load(["areas"]);",
            length: 10
         ],
         Symbol()_7.r75ow15n03u: undefined,
         Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_j.r75ow15n0ac: undefined
      },
      description: "This operation is not permitted for the current object.",
      httpStatusCode: 400,
      innerError: null,
      message: "This operation is not permitted for the current object.",
      name: "RichApi.Error",
      stack: "InvalidOperation: This operation is not permitted for the current object.
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:26:321537)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/polyfill.js:1:76119)
   at e (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/polyfill.js:1:31843)",
      Symbol()_7.r75ow15n03u: undefined,
      Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_j.r75ow15n0ac: undefined,
      traceMessages: [
         length: 0
      ]
   }
```

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that you're not using `getMergedAreasOrNullObject` method correctly. When you us a `*OrNullObject` method, you have to check to see if it is null. See [*OrNullObject methods and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#ornullobject-methods-and-properties) for details.

Comment: @RickKirkham wether or not I check if its null shouldn't affect the procedure, thats just an if then null check. I removed that from the code to create a MCVE., minimal being operative word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code suddenly works again. My suspicion is the API/CDN changed.. This is the downfall of using the newest tech I suppose, one thing I knew about VBA, it was stable!